# Unique constraint validation order MySql/MariaDb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Just ran into an interesting question about UNIQUE CONSTRAINT validation orders.

Is it possible to tell Mysql(or MariaDB) to validate one unique constraint before the other (`id` before `email`)?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  `pk` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (pk),
  UNIQUE INDEX id (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX email (email),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If the `id` constraint fails it is a duplicate submission and if the `email` fails it's a business failure creating a second user with an already registered email.

Ofcourse it could be solved by searching for it first but this would somehow be smoother.

Comment: You could make the email index a `constraint`, and differentiate between the 2 like that. In both cases the `insert` should fail, right?

Comment: HoneyBadger unique constraint | unique index = same thing. What I want is to guarantee that the id index will fail (if violated) before the email index.

Comment: Yeah, I know they are (almost) the same, but I thought you just wanted to differentiate between them. They give different error codes, that's why I suggested it. I don't think you can give an order the way you want. (edit: I'm not really sure about the error codes in mysql, I work mostly with sql server)